# python TypeError returning sorted list of objects

Tags: python, sorting, return

The point of this code is to compare IP address objects to a list of subnet objects that represent the scope for a piece of analysis to determine if the device should be included.  However, I also want to track what is in scope on each subnet.  I had it working and then realized that I really want to return the smallest matching subnet (largest netmask), not just the first match.  I changed the code to make a list of matches and wanted to sort results and just grab the first one (or -1 depending on which direction it sorts them)

Here is the code:

```
    def _ip_in_scope(self,ip_obj):
    # find smallest matching subnet
    match=[]
    for n in self.subnets:
        if ip_obj:
            if ip_obj in n:
                match.append(n)
    if match:
        try:
            return match.sort(key= lambda x: x.num_addresses)[0] 
        except:
            print (type(match[0]))
            print('Error returning subnet match.  Subnet list is:')
            pp(match)
            exit()
```

Here is the output:

Assessing IP scope
class ipaddress.IPv4Network
Error returning subnet match.
Subnet list is: [IPv4Network('10.120.5.0/24'), IPv4Network('10.120.5.0/24')]

I tried changing the return to

```
return sorted(match, key=lambda x: x.num_addresses)[0])
```

In this case, sending the copy did NOT cause the exception.  It also didn't return any values in my outputs.  The calling code is expecting either a single IP Address object or None to be returned.

I'm sure this is something simple, but it's also one of those things I've looked at for 2 hours without figuring it out.  :-(

Comment: `sort` doesn't return the list.

Comment: The output does not seem to have anything to do with the posted code (which only prints something if there is an error).

Comment: can you just do `match.sort()`? AFAIK the `key` is for the `sorted()` function and sorts a list of dictionaries by the values of a key

Comment: OK sort not returning the list is helpful.  So I was on the right path with sorted and just had something else wrong.

Comment: Found the answer to the rest of the problem too.  I had two similar fields in my output file and was looking at the wrong one.  I had a working version, but wasn't seeing it.  So the earlier version I had using sorted() worked.